# which layer to use batch normalization in multi layer perceptron?

Tags: regression, neural-networks, regularization

Hi I'm experimenting with deep neural network with 4 hidden layer and one output layer (regression layer). I found this working without regularization so I want to find out which regularization works well.

However, it seems dropout and batch normalization don't work well in the test data. It makes overall score worse (Mean Squared Error in regression task). I don't get why this happen and trying to find out what I did wrong.

am I supposed to apply batch normalization at all 4 hidden layer?

Comment: Are you using dropout during the test phase? You are supposed to use it only during the training phases. Maybe that's why you get worse score. Other than that batch normalization can be applied independently on all layers.

Comment: @Djib2011 No I don't use dropout at test phase. I used (0.9, 0.8, 0.5, 0.5) at training phase staring from lower layer but It didn't seem to work.

Comment: Is there can be experiment that regularizer don't work? It could I guess if you make up example but It has really low probability right?

Comment: I think that 0.9 probability is a bit harsh. You should try lowering it to 0.5. The problem with over-regularization is that it may cause your model to underfit. That could be the problem in your case

Comment: @Djib2011 So 0.5 rate for all 4 layers? how about batch normalization? It seems people don't use dropout these days. Is it generally better?

Comment: Yes I think it's better, and yes you could use BN in every layer.

Comment: If you can tell us some thing about the structure of the data, about its nature, and if you can tell us something about the structure of the net work, then answering those questions becomes a lot more concrete.